# Hidden structures

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

There is a lot of talk about "hidden structures" in the realm of mathematics: hidden structures in the ZFC system, hidden structures in the natural number system, and so on. Saunders Mac Lane poignantly formulated:

> Mathematics is a network of hidden structures.  [[Mac Lane 1980](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CTGDC/CTGDC_1980__21_4/CTGDC_1980__21_4_353_0/CTGDC_1980__21_4_353_0.pdf),
>   p. 362].

I'd like to know how this manner of speaking is to be understood concretely:

> How and why can a structure be *hidden*?

Can this be made comprehensible to a layman?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of times when a set admits more structure than you might have originally noticed.  A pretty elementary example is when a combinatorial or set-theoretical device turns out to admit an action by a group $G$, making it into a $G$-set.  This is what underlines the unreasonable effectiveness of group theory in combinatorics.  So a laymen's example might be something as simple as the 15-puzzle or the Rubik's cube.  Or maybe you run into a group that itself admits a "hidden" action from some other group, further illuminating its structure.  Or maybe your abelian group turns out to be an $R$-module for some ring $R$ of interest.  All of these phenomena have occurred many times in the development of mathematics.

On a (only slightly) different front, maybe you find that the set of points on a geometric curve admits a shockingly important group structure.  Ditto for other geometric objects like the space of line bundles on a projective variety.  Or maybe a topological space (or a group) admits the structure of a Lie group.  Or maybe a space parameterizing some interesting collection of objects turns out to actually be a fine moduli space for such objects.

The list goes on and on.  In fact, I think it would be a reasonable stance (among many other valid such stances) that the search for hidden structures *is* the process of doing mathematics.

Comment: Thanks! I do have to carefully think about each of your examples. Having deeply understood only one of them would mean a lot, wouldn't it?

Comment: "the search for hidden structures _is_ the process of doing mathematics" -- nice! +1

Comment: @HansStricker:  Well, I'll let you know once I deeply understand any of them.  :)

Comment: @HansStricker:  Seriously, though, understanding the role of group theory in combinatorics is not particularly difficult (google, for example, applications of the orbit-stabilizer theorem).  I think that'll give you a feel for what I was trying to convey without having to, e.g., learn sheaf cohomology.